# find coordinates of point from two merged segments

Tags: geometry

I have coordinates of points A and B and lengths |AC|and |BC|.

How can I find coordinates of point C?

[image: picture]

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. Each length will give a circle of feasible solutions.
However there are several possible scenarios for the intersection of two circles:

1. no intersection (should not happen, if a $C$ exists)
2. one intersection point ($C$ is on the line between $A$ and $B$)
3. two intersection points
4. infinite many intersection points (only possible if A = B)

[image: the situation]

These cases will show up in the algebraic solution of the problem:
$$
(x,y)^\top \in C_A \iff (x - a_x)^2 + (y - a_y)^2 = l_1^2 \\
(x,y)^\top \in C_B \iff (x - b_y)^2 + (y - b_y)^2 = l_2^2
$$

Answer (score 0):

Apply the Pythagorean distance formula to get the system of equations $$(a_1-c_1)^2 + (a_2-c_2)^2 = l_1^2$$ $$(b_1-c_1)^2 + (b_2-c_2)^2 = l_2^2$$ Then solve them.